Accessing a fifo from windows via samba doesn't work, no obvious reason why
I tried reading from a fifo on Windows via samba to see if it worked or not (I might have something interesting to do with it if it did), and found that it does not. ReadFile() returns 0 bytes immediately where it would be expected to block.
An internet search found one nice old google groups thread. https://groups.google.com/g/linux.samba/c/lkkziMXkgP4 So, this used to work, in 2011. Fun.
This is my smb.conf with sensitive material and comments removed.
[global]
   name resolve order = bcast host lmhosts wins
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   security = ads
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   min protocol = SMB2
   client signing = mandatory
   server signing = mandatory
   idmap uid = 10000-20000
   idmap gid = 10000-20000
   template homedir = /home/%D/%U
   template shell = /bin/bash
   root preexec = /etc/samba/makehomedir.sh %U
   usershare allow guests = yes

[allusers]
   comment = "User Home Directories"
   guest ok = no
   read only = no

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/tmp
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

The fifo is in my home directory. Saying it needs to be in a special directory is an answer I can test for.
There's one important thing you don't see. Hide special files is not set.
So the question is: Is this a misconfiguration, a bug in samba, or is this really not expected to work anymore?
Samba version 4.17.12
